# Excel SUMPRODUCT/SUMIFS Criteria not in Defined Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have created a smaller version of an issue I'm having in a personal finance excel sheet. I'm sure it's simple, but I haven't been able to crack it for about 3 weekends.

[image: Sheet snapshot]

- B1 and B2 have a defined name of 'good'
- Attempting to match everything in Jan. '17 whose C column is not defined in 'good'
- The expected value is 50, the current result is 137. (Simplifying to `SUMPRODUCT({70;67})`)
- Here is the actual sheet with some fake data in case it is helpful

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this sumproduct instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B7:B10,(A7:A10>= A4)*(A7:A10< B4)*(ISERROR(MATCH(C7:C10,good,0))))
```

[image]